# How to Integrate NodeJs in Existing .Net MVC application Using EdgeJs?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, node.js

Can any one suggest another way to integrate NodeJs in .Net MVC application? I am now using the following code:

```
public class Startup
{
        public async Task<object> Invoke(dynamic input)
        {
            DepartmentRep person = new DepartmentRep(new MvcAppUsingEdgeJSMongoDbContext());
           var department= person.GetAllDepartments();
            //var department = "hello";
            return department;
        }
}

public class DepartmentController : Controller
{

    DepartmentRepository departmentRepository = new DepartmentRepository(new MvcAppUsingEdgeJSMongoDbContext());

    string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["connectionString"].ToString();
    public ViewResult Index()
    {
        // var clrMethod = Edge.Func("DepartmentRep.cs");
        var getData = Edge.Func("./DepartmentRep.dll");

        // return View(clrMethod);
       return View(departmentRepository.GetAllDepartments());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me, you may have a misunderstanding of the EdgeJs use case.
Your Startup/Invoke class/Signature is meant to be called from Node(JavaScript), 
And from the code you are showing it looks like you are loading .Net from .Net

Also , as the Invoke signature suggest, It should be asynchronous.

If you want to use node from .Net side.  You should check the project documentation from
[scripting-nodejs-from-clr](https://github.com/tjanczuk/edge/tree/master#scripting-nodejs-from-clr) downwards.

```
var func = Edge.Func(@"
            return function (data, callback) {
                callback(null, 'Node.js welcomes ' + data);
            }
        ");
```

As you can see there the wrapped code is Javascript, this time running in .Net more specifically running in Node.
The perfect use case IMMO is the [Socket-Server](https://github.com/tjanczuk/edge/tree/master#how-to-use-external-nodejs-modules), that is, something Node does better than .Net (IMMO again)

Which is in perfect contrast with the .Net Ado Sql Server access from NodeJs, a .Net Specialization from NodeJs context